# How do I change git committer's name?

Tags: git, command

I'm a student learning how to use git.
I created a repository and added a small project on my git.
But I'd like to change the name of committer in the picture.
I tried `git config --global user.name` and `git commit --amend --author`
but both didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Once you've made some commit, that commit cannot be changed at all. You can make a new and *different* commit (with different hash ID) that's the same in all other ways; is that sufficient? Note that if you look at the original commit, it will continue to be unchanged; only looking at the *new* commit (its new-and-improved replacement) will show any other name.

Answer (score 0):

Try following command.

```
$ git config user.name "John Doe" // for name change
$ git config user.email "john@doe.org" // for email change
```